# Android how to test canvas UI jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-canvas, ui-testing

I have a custom canvas component. I want to test canvas UI objects like rect, line, text, etc. How should I test this sample UI?

```
         Canvas(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(canvasHeight.dp)
                .pointerInput(Unit) {
                    detectTapGestures { offset ->
                        touchPosition.value = offset
                    }
                }
        )
        { 
              drawArc(
                color = Color(0xFFf04231),
                startAngle = -90f,
                sweepAngle = 180f,
                useCenter = true,
                size = Size(size.width * .50f, size.height * .50f),
                topLeft = Offset(size.width * .25f, 0f)
              )
              drawPath(path = path, color = Color.White.copy(alpha = .90f))
              drawCircle(
                brush = Brush.verticalGradient(sunColor),
                radius = width.times(.17f),
                center = Offset(width.times(.35f), height.times(.35f))
              )
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way, for me, to make the UI test for a canvas fun is to use the screenshot test. In my case, I used Paparazzi, here is the link to the GitHub page:
https://github.com/cashapp/paparazzi